# Script to session timeout after 30 mins, doesn't works in Windows

Tags: php, session-timeout

This is my code to end sessión after 30 minutes inactivity, in Linux works fine but not in Windows.

**Create sessión**

```
$_SESSION['clientdan']['user'] = $username;
$_SESSION['clientdan']['tl'] = time();
```

**any_file.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$max_time = 1800;
$current = time();

if(!isset($_SESSION['clientdan']['user']) ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['clientdan']['tl'])){
        $_SESSION['clientdan']['tl'] = time();
    } else {
        $session_life = $current - $_SESSION['clientdan']['tl'];

        if ($session_life > $max_time) {
            header('Location: include/logout.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['clientdan']['tl'] = time();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
......
......
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call:

```
session_cache_expire($max_time);
```

This will increase the session timeout.